# Reproduce javaFX focus effect

Tags: java, javafx

I would like to reproduce the same focus effect that the JavaFX modena theme has by default, when you click on a button for example. This in order to apply this effect on a Shape gaining focus.

I don't work with FXML and CSS, but I could try it if it is easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In modena multiple background fills are combined to achieve this effect. For obvious reasons this is not applicable to shapes. (`Shape`s do not have a background property and there's no fill available allow you to change the color ortogonal to the edges at every possible point of arbitrary shapes.)

You could use a `DropShadow` effect to achieve a look similar to the focus look of controls though:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Circle circle = new Circle(100, null);
    circle.setStrokeWidth(5);
    circle.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
    Effect effect = new DropShadow(BlurType.GAUSSIAN, Color.DODGERBLUE, 5, 0.75, 0, 0);

    Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane(circle), 250, 250);
    scene.setOnMouseClicked(evt -> circle.setEffect(circle.getEffect() == null ? effect : null));
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

**Result** (left without effect, right with effect applied)

[image: result screenshot]

The `DropShadow` effect can also be applied via CSS, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#typeeffect